# Spec did not pass validation

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I used `pod spec create` to create the .podspec file in my project(Swift) folder. Inside project folder, source files are in Source folder, demo project is in Example folder. LICENSE was also created.

But the Spec did not pass validation, I received `The spec did not pass validation, due to 2 errors`

Here is my PodSpec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "StickerTextView"
  s.version      = "0.1.0"
  s.summary      = "add text(multiple line support) to imageView, edit, rotate or resize them as you want, then render the text on image"

  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/luiyezheng/StickerTextView"

  s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }

  s.author       = { "luiyezheng" => "luiyezheng@126.com" }

  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/luiyezheng/StickerTextView.git", :tag => "0.1.0" }

  s.platform = :ios, "8.0"

  s.source_files  = "Source"

  s.requires_arc = false

  s.frameworks = "UIKit"

end
```

Here is the detail of error:

```
[!] Error installing StickerTextView
 -> StickerTextView (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | name: The name of the spec should match the name of the file.
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error ([!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/luiyezheng/StickerTextView.git /tmp/d20160422-22078-3jc64h --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.1.0

Cloning into '/tmp/d20160422-22078-3jc64h'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 0.1.0 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 0.1.0 not found in upstream origin
) during validation.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 2 errors.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:77:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you paste here those 2 errors please?

Comment: @LucaD detail of these 2 errors wasn't shown in terminal, how could I get them?

Comment: @LucaD I just edited my question

Comment: So, did you understand now where is the problem?

Comment: @LucaD I know how to handle the `The name of the spec should match the name of the file`, but what about the second one? `fatal: Remote branch 0.1.0 not found in upstream origin
) during validation.`

Comment: Is there tag `0.1.0` on your github repo?

Comment: @LucaD Just Got it :-) Thanks

Comment: Error # 2 is solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038659/issue-when-creating-my-first-cocoapod

Comment: Ensure the matched set has the proper case name

Comment: @ilovecomputer How did you fix the first error. The name of the spec should match the name of the file. the names match I still don't understand why I'm getting that error

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as:

> - ERROR | name: The name of the spec should match the name of the file.

I was getting it because:

- My PodSpec was named `Foo.PodSpec`
- Within the PodSpec the name of the PodSpec was mentioned as such:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'Bar'
```

CocoaPods want's it so that the **name of the file** (Foo.PodSpec), matches with the name that you give to your spec in the PodSpec **file**.

They may look similar, but they're totally different.

One is the name of a file, the other is the name of the Pod.

I suppose if there's not a 1:1 mapping then things can't be found or disambiguated as easily.

### Solution

Either solution works:

- Change the name of PodSpec to `Bar.PodSpec`
- Change the name of the Pod in the PodSpec to `Foo` i.e. `s.name = 'Foo'`