# Issue when creating my first CocoaPod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to create my first pod and is following this tutorial:
http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-cocoapods/

But when I do:

```
pod spec lint GLLingoManager.podspec
```

I get following error:

```
$ pod spec lint GLLingoManager.podspec

 -> GLLingoManager (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [OSX] unknown: Encountered an unknown error ([!] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/xeppen/GLLingoManager.git /var/folders/v6/tdz6zc7j10j_k0pc1vy627zm0000gn/T/d20160504-76297-8l71fj --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.1.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/v6/tdz6zc7j10j_k0pc1vy627zm0000gn/T/d20160504-76297-8l71fj'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 0.1.0 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 0.1.0 not found in upstream origin
) during validation.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
```

I dont understand what is wrong. What should I do?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[Add a 0.1.0 version for your github repo.](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) Image from Github incase the link dies:

[image: How to create a version.]

Comment: This helped me much

Answer (score 5):

You have pointed to a branch called 0.1.0 in your podspec, and you simply need to push a branch of that name to github. Many people use tags instead of branches to indicate which commit to use for each pod version, and I suggest that you do this instead of pointing to a branch. Please post the source section of your podspec for more specific details.

Comment: What if we're using http rather than git?

Comment: HTTP of an archive? If you aren't using git, you won't get a cloning issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a tag to your branch in terminal:

```
git tag 0.1.0
git push --tags
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the following command line will create a problem, if you are copy pasting into terminal.

Example

```
//incorrect
git tag ‘0.1.0’
//Will create a tag ‘0.1.0’

//correct
git tag '0.1.0'
//will create a tag 0.1.0
```

So better to type the single quotes, it may prevent this kind of unexpected issues.
And go check your repo whether these tags are created properly.