# Unable to push my pod

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, git-branch

Following is my pod spec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = "name"
s.version          = "0.1"
s.summary          = "summary"
s.description      = "desc"
s.homepage         = "https://github.com/url"
s.license          = 'MIT'
s.author           = { "name" => "mail@mail.com" }
s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/name/name.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }
s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
s.requires_arc = true

# If more than one source file: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source_files
s.source_files = 'file.c' 

end
```

when I tried running `pod trunk push name.podspec --verbose`, it is providing the following error

> fatal: Remote branch 0.1 not found in upstream origin

I tried whats in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038659/issue-when-creating-my-first-cocoapod) to check the branch number but the releases tab is not found in my repository.

How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is searching your git repo for a branch that has been tagged as 0.1.

You should be able to fix it with this:

```
git tag 0.1

git push --tags
```

Comment: but when it try to push the pod, it is firing the same error